# Potential employer is taking a long time to set up an interview. Is this a sign of bad company culture?

Tags: interviewing, time-management

After applying for a position in a local company, I received an email about setting up an interview. My response was that I could do it anytime after my current working hours this week (I told them my schedule) or any other time if they give me a 24 hour notice to let my current boss know I need time off. This happened on a Monday.

Fast forward to Friday morning (4 days later), they responded and apologized for the delay in getting back to me. They also asked what time I could come in next Thursday (which is now two days from now). I asked them if 2pm would work. That brings us to today, which is about 3 full business days later and I still haven't received a reply.

Could this be indicative of a bad company culture of poor planning and/or not respecting people's time?

Comment: It might be, or it might not be. How much you decide to read into the behaviour of one person is up to you.

Comment: Obviously, this is a matter of opinion but personally, I like the fact that they prioritize meeting the needs of their customers and current employees over potential employees.  I know it's annoying from your perspective but chances are they're just too busy with their own work to prioritize scheduling your interview.

Answer (score 2):

> Could this be indicative of a bad company culture of poor planning and/or not respecting people's time?

Not necessarily, it may be a premature conclusion to say that.

Recruitment processes take time. How much time depends on each company and their inner processes and people involved. It is not rare for them to reply some days after, as they are surely also doing other tasks and most probably evaluating other offers, for this and any other opening they may have.

What can give you a better clue if they have a poor planning culture and respect of people's time is when you have your interview. There you can ask questions that will give you a better concept of the culture that company has, and you will probably see if they are indeed lacking in their planning skills.

I suggest you go forward with the process, but keep your options open. If you see they continue to delay on their responses, or see any other indication of their lack of planning then you would probably do better seeking job elsewhere, as you should not take a job where you are not comfortable or that is not a good fit for you.